# In VB.NET, a MySQL connection won't close after calling conn.close or conn.dispose or even with USING

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am using [MySQL Workbench](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL_Workbench). If I open a connection (in Visual Basic) to MySQL it will show that a connection is opened. If I close the connection, (*in* MySQL Workbench), it shows the connection is still open. If I try to reopen the same connection, it will open and it will close without any problem. However, MySQL Workbench shows that the first connection is still open. It stays open until I exit the application.

```
   Try
        Using myConnection As New MySqlConnection(_ServerString_vip)
            myConnection.Open()

            myConnection.Close()

            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error getting Username Information.")
    End Try
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do some reading on connection pooling in ADO.NET.

A `DbConnection` object is actually quite light-weight and exists at a higher level than the actual database connection.  When you open a `DbConnection` object, a low-level database connection is opened.  When you close the `DbConnection` object, the low-level database connection remains open for some time.  That's because opening and closing it is an expensive operation.  If you open another `DbConnection` with the same connection string, the same low-level database connection will be reused.  The low-level connection is only closed if it remains unused for some time.

This is not something you have to worry about.  This is the way it is and has always been in ADO.NET and the system handles it automatically.  You keep doing what you're doing, i.e. creating `DbConnection` objects with `Using` statements, and the system will take care of the rest.

By the way, there's no point opening the connection explicitly when calling `Fill` or `Update` on a data adapter.  Both those methods will automatically open the connection and close it again afterwards.  You should only open the connection explicitly if you want it to stay open after the `Fill` or `Update` call, i.e. if you have more work to do over that connection.

Comment: I appreciate  your answer. The above code is irrelevant. It was too late for my to edit it.

Answer (score -1):

*jmcilhinney* is absolutely right. I was looking all over the Internet and I couldn't find an answer for that. Hopefully, this question will help a lot of people. And *eventually* the connection will die automatically.

Comment: This should have been posted as a comment rather than an answer. An answer should be a self-contained solution to the question as asked.